# How to make random more accurate?

Tags: java

```
while (tNumbers.size() < 27) {
  int randNum = Helper.random(0, randNumbers.length() - 1);
  tNumbers.add(randNumbers.remove(randNum));
}
```

The `randNumbers` is an array of numbers from `1` to `99`, and here I'am filling the `tNumbers` array, until it has 27 elements (numbers). So this code may work too long if the `randNum` many times will fire to the unexistant keys.

How to make the random be more accurate? I mean to make it never miss, and always get the existant key in the `randNumbers`.

Comment: How can something be accurate and random at the same time?

Comment: So you need an array of 27 random numbers between 1 and 99 without duplicates?

Comment: yeap thats what i need

Answer (score 11):

Here's an idea:

1. Create a list of numbers from 1 to 99
2. Shuffle it using [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)
3. Take the first 27 elements from it

By doing the above, you won't have to keep generating random numbers until the 27 elements are obtained. Here's a proof of concept:

```
List<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(99);
for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i++)
    randomNumbers.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(randomNumbers);
List<Integer> random27 = randomNumbers.subList(0, 27);
```

Comment: Sorry I have no upvotes left for today, but I'd upvote it if I could. :(

Comment: @AdamArold I'll upvote for you.

Comment: Simple, elegant, too bad I can only upvote once :)

Comment: That's what I call creative. Nice one!

Comment: great!, accept in 8 minutes

Comment: @user3016968 my pleasure! it was a fun little piece of code to program. Please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer, if it was helpful for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are already "never missing" because you are choosing randomly one of the remaining numbers with equal probability every time. `List.remove()` doesn't leave gaps; just `get()` the element at your random index before calling remove with that index.

```
while (tNumbers.size() < 27) {
  int randNum = Helper.random(0, randNumbers.length() - 1);
  //both extremes inclusive!
  tNumbers.add(randNumbers.get(randNum));
  randNumbers.remove(randNum);
}
```

What might or might not be accurate is the distribution of your `Helper.random()` function; how did you implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Random does not mean unique, it means Random, which means it could randomly create the same number `N` number of times randomly. If you want unique numbers don't use anything that is Random, use something that is unique like a a perfect hash function that will guarantee no duplicates.